# Sull'uso figurato del vocabolo "sberla"

Tags: word-usage

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te* di Paola Mastrocola, pubblicato da Einaudi,  ho letto (il corsivo è mio):

> Gheri era a lezione. Stava seguendo Diritto commerciale, e certo che a quel punto si distrasse: con quella *sberla* di sms da non crederci! Cosa voleva dire? Si alzò scombinando una ventina di compagni che contrassero ginocchia e libri per farla passare, e sparí nell’atrio a smanettare sul telefonino, a chiamare quella Cami per parlarle a voce, per capirci qualcosa.

La mia domanda è sull'uso che se ne fa del vocabolo "sberla". È chiaro che si tratta di un uso figurato, ma non ho trovato nulla al riguardo nei dizionari che ho consultato. È un'invenzione dell'autrice? Oppure tale uso è diventato comune nella lingua italiana?

Comment: Penso che in molte lingue ci sia più di un caso di parola che letteralmente indica un colpo fisico e figuratamente un evento con un impatto psicologico, a partire, per l'italiano, da “colpo”, appunto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sberla](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/sberla):

> - *1888; voce di area sett., di orig. incerta.*
> - schiaffo, ceffone: riceversi una bella sberla, una sberla ogni tanto ci vuole, prendere a sberle qcn.
> - sport spec. nel gioco del calcio, tiro particolarmente forte: una sberla che ha preso il palo.

In senso più generale e figurato si usa  "sberla" per indicare qualsiasi  cosa che abbia un  forte impatto  fisico e/o emotivo:

Ad esempio:

> - *Il conto al ristorante è stato una vera sberla,* (un conto salato)
> - *Una sberla di ragazza,* (una bella ragazza)

Nel caso citato l'sms ha creato sconcerto e preoccupazione in Gheri, che corre fuori per telefonare e capire di cosa si tratta.

Comment: Grazie della risposta, @Josh61! Se ho capito bene, si tratta di un uso comune, vero?

Comment: @Charo - Si è di uso molto comune ed informale.

Comment: Personalmente non direi che questo significato sia molto comune! Mi sembra una variante regionale, anzi, locale. 
Vorrei aggiungere che, in zona Milano almeno, c'è un altro modo figurato per usare questa parola. "Una sberla di.." significa "una gran quantità di, un gran pezzo di". 
Esempio: mi hanno dato una sberla di torta. non sono riuscita a finirla tutta"

Comment: @AltGei - che sia un uso regionale  (nord) è specificato nella mia risposta. Che significhi" una gran quantità di", un "gran pezzo di", mi sembra chiaro dagli esempi che ho fatto. Non so di che zona sei, ma ti posso garantire che da Venezia a Milano, e oltre è un'espressione comune.

Comment: se prendiamo l'esempio iniziale, non si può parafrasare con "una gran quantità di sms". Si parla non di quantità, ma di forza emotiva, come dici tu. Perciò io ho portato un secondo esempio della parola.

Comment: Stiamo dicendo la stessa cosa, la "gran quantità" a cui ti riferisci può generare un impatto emotivo, una sberla. (Una sberla di torta, una gran quantità, un'emozione positiva o negativa secondo il contesto)